# Ghostery suddenly blocking Stack Exchange JavaScript in Chrome ("StackExchange is not defined")

Tags: support

Every other request, either on the front page or in a question, yields:

> VM175 any-page:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
>       at VM175

This is caused by `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=53401d8fe7e5` being blocked:

> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

This happens only on https://stackoverflow.com, not on Meta nor on other network sites. It is Ghostery, reporting to be blocking your JS as a tracker.

Did something recently get put in there that might get picked up as tracking software?

Comment: Use script blockers, get your scripts blocked…  You may rather want to report this to Ghostery…?!

Comment: I've been using them for years, and suddenly one out of two requests fails, @deceze. Just wondering whether SO did a sneaky push, but apart from some swapped minimized variable letters, there's no difference between the working and non-working JS...

Comment: It's more likely that the extension's block list has changed.

Comment: Simply adding the site to the trusted list in Ghostery works fine. I trust SE not to do anything stupid, the problem is that Ghostery does not have a way to trust entire domains with all their subdomains... So I have to click the "trust" button for every site individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same thing, I clicked on the extension icon and under "Unknown trackers" there was one for Stack Exchange. I changed it from "Anonymize on this site" to "Trust on this site", and now everything works normally again.

As far as I can tell, it has to do with the `v` query string parameter in the URL to request static files like CSS or JS from the CDN, which Ghostery interprets as tracking and tries to change its value to `ghostery`.

Comment: If Ghostery would do that, that'd be pretty terrible. The `v` is a version indicator, making sure the version of the HTML doesn't mismatch the JS/CSS because of caching, not a tracking feature, and it's pretty widespread on many sites. Modifying that to be the same URL after the indicator changed would ruin that method and cause caching-related errors.