# Weird UI bug? Unable to use the site properly

Tags: bug, user-interface, user-experience

I asked about this in [math.meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31187/weird-ui-glitches?noredirect=1), but I realized that this is more of a sitewide issue for me, so I thought that SO might be the place to ask.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on MacOS, and the site has been rendering super weirdly (see below)[image]

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: Are you using [Ghostery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393322/ghostery-suddenly-blocking-stack-exchange-javascript-in-chrome-stackexchange-i)?

Comment: First thing to try is to disable any chrome extensions ...

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I am. Let me try disabling. (Edit: That did the trick. Interesting, because this never was a problem before)

Comment: Can you isolate the bug (that is, which extension)?

Comment: I thought it was Ghostery, but it's still happening.